# Selenium-Webdriver, driver.manage().window().getRect() return wrong value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying get a window size by Selenium nodejs by this function

```
driver.manage().window().getRect()
```

This is the Value which i got

```
{ x: -7, y: -7, width: 1550, height: 840 }
```

But the actual window is this size.
[image]

Anyone know how can i make the value correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows rect will return your browser window size

```
driver.manage().window().getRect()
```

To get the html size you can use find element,

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName('body')).getRect();
```